# manual anti ads extension for google chrome (or Firefox)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, advertisements

I know about AdBlock extension. But in general, I don't want to block all ads. I'd like an extension, which allows me to Ctrl-click (or use another shortcut-click) on an ad which is disturbing and intelligently remove it from  the page that I am browsing.

I know it could be done also, by right clicking on a page, opening the Inspection panel, click on the Loop tool, click the add, go up the DOM and highlight `<object>` and press Delete. But it's too long.

I remember once reading about a fancy jquery something, which blows elements on page in a spectacular way (unfortunately no idea what was the name). Perhaps something like this would do. Anything, the simpler, the better, But not automatic, just allow me to click&go. (in fact, it could allow to get rid of anything on the page, not only ad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually achieve this with [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom):

- To avoid it from blocking anything by default, uncheck all items in the *Filter lists*.
- To block a specific ad, right-click it and choose `AdBlock -> Block this ad`.

This would have the advantage of remembering your actions.

If you don't want to use AdBlock, you could try out this simple user script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          NukeIt
// @description   Nukes HTML elements with a single click.
// ==/UserScript==

var nukeItSetup = function() {
    function nukeIt(what) {
        if(!event.ctrlKey)
            return;
        event.preventDefault();
        var now = Number(new Date());
        if(now < nukeItTimer)
            return;
        nukeItTimer = now + 100;
        if(event.altKey) {
            if(nukeItElements.length)
                nukeItElements.pop().style.display = nukeItProperties.pop();
        }
        else {
            nukeItElements.push(what);
            nukeItProperties.push(what.style.display);
            what.style.display = 'none';
        }   
    }
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i = 0, j = all.length; i < j; i++)
        all[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', function(){nukeIt(this)});
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = 'var nukeItTimer = 0, nukeItElements = [], nukeItProperties = []; (' + nukeItSetup.toString() + ')();';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

How to use:

- To install, (temporarily) save the code as `nuke-it.user.js`, drag and drop the file in Chrome and click `Continue` when asked if you want to.
- To hide a HTML element, right-click it while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
- To unhide the elements you hid (in reverse order), right-click anywhere while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, AdBlock indeed has this option, it was just a little hidden. I also installed NukeIt (by dragging it on the browser address bar) and it's really nice. It sometimes doesn't work on flash, e.g. on YouTube it won't delete the main video. But it nukes ads and it's funny!

Comment: @camcam: That's because they placed a bunch of HTML elements over each other. If you click it several times, it will eventually disappear.